# ActivityNotFoundException when testing on a device running 2.3

Tags: android, calendar

I have successfully added event to Native calendar, and works fine for Android API Level 14 or higher.

I tried @VishalKhakhkhar's code, but i am still not able to resolve this issue? I'm getting error : **No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event** when testing on a device running 2.3.6

see my updated code below, try to resolve this issue:-

```
    Button btnEvents = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnEvents.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            long startMillis = 0; 
            long endMillis = 0; 
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            beginTime.set(2014, 1, 16, 16, 0);  
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis(); 
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            endTime.set(2014, 1, 16, 22, 30);
            endMillis= endTime.getTimeInMillis();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT).setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endMillis)
                    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Title")
                    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Description")
                    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Location")
                    .putExtra(Reminders.HAS_ALARM, true)
                    .putExtra(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_DEFAULT);
                    startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intent.putExtra("title", "Title");
                intent.putExtra("description", "Description");
                intent.putExtra("beginTime", startMillis);
                intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
                intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.endMillis);
                intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Location");
                intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }               
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Did you checked [this example ?](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html)

Comment: it's nothing just a custom calendar, to add some pre-defined events, it'll not work for me

Comment: Have u got any solution for the same.. ?? I also have to implement it in my project...

Comment: @Bhavna no still looking for answer... may be an angel will come...whenever i will get my solution will tell you for sure, and if you will get some solution then let me know ok !

Answer (score 0):

If u wish to add an event directly into the Calendar,i.e., without opening an intent, u can use the following code..,

```
    try
    {
    Calendar calendarStart = getCalendarFromISO(startDate);
    Calendar calendarEnd = getCalendarFromISO(endDate);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));

      ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(Events.DTSTART, calendarStart.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.DTEND, calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis());
      values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
 //       values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
      values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
//        values.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
//        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
      values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

// Provider for Calendar
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {

         eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
     } else 
     {

         eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
     }
      Uri uri = cr.insert(eventsUri, values);

//Returns the id for last added event
      eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    Log.v("Calendar", "Calender Event Added" + eventID );

     } 
catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

       }
```

// Method for formatting the date

```
 public static Calendar getCalendarFromISO(String dateString) {
    //dateString = dateString.trim().replaceAll(":00$", "00"); // Changing format for SimpleDateFormat

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO8601DATEFORMAT, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        Date date = dateformat.parse(dateString);
        calendar.setTime(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return calendar;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT).setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis()).putExtra(Events.TITLE, eventname)
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, strDesctription)
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, eventLoc).putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Reminders.HAS_ALARM, true).putExtra(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_DEFAULT).putExtra(Reminders.DURATION, 45)
        .putExtra(Reminders.MINUTES, 60);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("title", eventname);
    intent.putExtra("description", strDesctription);
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("eventLocation", eventLoc);
    intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: still not resolved for lower versions, see my updated code, used yours - getting Unfortunately App has stopped

Comment: let me know where it cause problem.. that I can help you further

Comment: but in my case it's not working, getting : No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are getting

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT
>   typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event

with that particular device implies that there's no application registered on it that can handle the intent. Period.

The best you can do is to catch the exception and show the user a message telling that there's no way to handle that operation on his/her device.

Other thing you can do is suggest to install an app that can handle it, namely a calendar type of app.