# Sync Calendar events, delete Events in android

Tags: android, events, calendar, synchronization

i have two problems.

1. The first problem is not a programmatically problem. I insert an event from my app into the google calendar on the device. But these event was not sync with google server. But when i open these event with the calendar app on my phone and save the event, without editing, the event was synced. :(
   I have test this on my asus tablet and it works fine but not on my sony xperia handy.
2. I'm rading all futured events from my google calendar into my app and saved in my sql db. That works fine. Than I will editing these events and make a update. But i can't delete or update these events from my app. 
   What is wrong?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

in first question , you need to force sync ....

see

[Trigger Android Calendar to sync after adding events programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094637/trigger-android-calendar-to-sync-after-adding-events-programmatically)

or

[sync event added programmatically with google calendar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918968/sync-event-added-programmatically-with-google-calendar-in-android)