# How to Add Google Calendar Event in your Android App?

Tags: android, web, events, calendar

I want when user add a google calendar event in my android app and it should reflect in my android calendar app and web google calendar also ? how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Intent to add an event to Google Calendar as described in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#AddEvent)

Example intent:

```
public void addEvent(String title, String location, long begin, long end) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, begin)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end);
  if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Example intent filter:

```
<activity ...>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I want this in background. is there possible ?

Comment: No that's an intent so the user will have prefilled the data and add the event himself. If you need this done in the bg, then the [Calendar Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#insert-calendar) is the way to go.

Comment: I am doing with Calendar content Provider the event added in my android device calendar but not in google calendar.

Comment: can you help me how to add the event in google calendar also.
I want the event here https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/day

Comment: I see, so the event does not appear in the Google Calendar app?  Are you sure it's not just a filtering issue in the Google Calendar UI.

Comment: its showing in google calendar android app but when I am checking it on the web side it not showing ?

Comment: yeah I undestand, but since the event is inserted then I dont believe it's a coding issue. Is the gmail calendar synced(from your phone's account settings) after the event insertion?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Ok so it seems that syncing is indeed the problem and you have to manually sync the content resolver. Take a look at this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094637/trigger-android-calendar-to-sync-after-adding-events-programmatically) that is already answered.